# Patent purchase

Tags: ownership, uspublication, number, us6550709

I would like to own this patent but have no idea how to go about redeeming this patent.
Who will I need to contact in order to purchase the patent. It appears to be inactive.
Charlie

Comment: You neglected to provide a patent number. You may try to find the assignee or original inventor. This forum may not be appropriate for this.

Comment: Hi Ron,Here is the patent number US 6550709 B2 the owner is currently in the Utah pen. It appears the patent is inactive.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "inactive". This patent expired in 2011 due to nonpayment of the 7 1/2 year maintenance fee. It is conceivable that the owner could petition to revive it on the basis that the nonpayment was unavoidable or inadvertent. After 2 years that might not fly. In any case, a third party (you) cannot come along and get rights to it by "redeeming" it from the patent office the way someone might buy abandoned land by paying the back property taxes. Theoretically, the owner could get it revived and then sell it to you.